# What are the some of the special usecases of general purpose registers

Tags: disassembly, assembly

Some of the general purpose registers are used for some specific reasons. For example `EAX` is used as an accumulator and to store return values, `ECX` is used as a counter, `ESI` and `EDI` are used to store the src and dst address, respectively. similarly, `ESP` and `EBP`.

Is there any specific use case for`EBX` register? and Is there anything else that I have missed special use cases of general purpose registers?

Thank you.

Comment: [Implicit uses and special-ness for each register](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347294/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

• AX/EAX/RAX: Accumulator

• BX/EBX/RBX: Base index (for use with arrays)

• CX/ECX/RCX: Counter

• DX/EDX/RDX: Data/general

• SI/ESI/RSI: Source index for string operations.

• DI/EDI/RDI: Destination index for string operations.

• SP/ESP/RSP: Stack pointer for top address of the stack.

• BP/EBP/RBP: Stack base pointer for holding the address of the current stack frame.

• IP/EIP/RIP: Instruction pointer. Holds the program counter, the current instruction address.

Segment registers:

• CS: Code Segment (used for IP)

• DS: Data Segment (used for MOV)

• SS: Stack Segment (used for SP)

• ES: Destination Segment (used for MOVS, etc.)

• FS: local store

• GS: local store

Comment: Note that the original 8086 design had a lot more limitations on what you could do with which register that current processors have. There's still stuff like `loop` which works on `cx` or its extensions, but most instructions that needed a specific (set of) register(s) on 8086 work with any, or almost any, register now.

Comment: specific case for [E/R]BX: xlat.

Comment: RIP is not a general purpose register. R11 also has a special purpose in kernel code. And even the above registers have a lot more special purposes than what you listed